# How to set environment variable for gradle wrapper command in gitlab CI?

Tags: gradle, gitlab, build.gradle, gitlab-ci, gradlew

```
./gradlew -i dev_task -Pdb_user=user1 -Pdb_pwd=pwd1
```

The above command works fine on windows and able to access environment variables, db_user and db_pwd, but not in gitlab CI when using the same command or exporting the variable before running the command,

```
Dev task:
  image: gradle:7.5.1-jdk11
  stage: dev-task
  before_script:    
    - export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_db_user=user1 # set env variable and didn't work
    - export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_db_pwd=pwd1 # set env variable and didn't work
  script:
    - ./gradlew -i dev_db_migration -Pdb_user=user1 -Pdb_pwd=pwd1  # set env variable here also and didn't work
```

In build.gradle, I am reading those 2 properties using

```
user1 = project.properties['db_user']
pwd1 = project.properties['db_pwd
```

Any suggestions how to set environment variable in gitlab CI and read it in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting ENV variables - you need to read them as `System.getEnv('ENV_VAR_NAME')`

when using gitlab CI/CD - the better way is to

1. set the 'Repository > Settings > CI/CD > Variables. ex: MYVAR1, 'xyz'
2. read in build.gradle as ex:
   `ext.myProjVarName = System.getEnv('ENV_VAR_NAME')`
3. after that you can access it normally like "$myProjVarName"